# The passed model is not callable and cannot be analyzed directly with the given masker! Model: Pipeline()

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, lightgbm, shap

I have trained a model then have saved its pickle, I want to perform a shap analysis on the validation set "X_val", I've set the code as follows:

```
import joblib
import shap
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier


# Load the model from the pickle file
model = joblib.load("model.pkl")

# Create an explainer object for the model
explainer = shap.Explainer(model)

# Compute SHAP values for the validation data
shap_values = explainer(X_val)
# Plot the SHAP values
shap.plots.waterfall(shap_values[0]) # Replace 0 with the index of the instance you want to visualize
```

but I got this error :

```
Exception: The passed model is not callable and cannot be analyzed directly with the given masker! Model: Pipeline(steps=[('column_selector',
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1911364825105189> in <module>
      5 
      6 # Create an explainer object for the model
----> 7 explainer = shap.Explainer(model)
      8 
      9 # Compute SHAP values for the validation data

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shap/explainers/_explainer.py in __init__(self, model, masker, link, algorithm, output_names, feature_names, linearize_link, **kwargs)
    166                 # if we get here then we don't know how to handle what was given to us
    167                 else:
--> 168                     raise Exception("The passed model is not callable and cannot be analyzed directly with the given masker! Model: " + str(model))
    169 
    170             # build the right subclass

Exception: The passed model is not callable and cannot be analyzed directly with the given masker! Model: Pipeline(steps=[('column_selector',
                 ColumnSelector(cols=['A', 'b', 'c']),
                ('standardizer', StandardScaler()),
                ('classifier',
                 LGBMClassifier(colsample_bytree=0.53,
                                lambda_l1=0.6423636335585889,
                                learning_rate=0.013, max_bin=173,
                                max_depth=9,
                                n_estimators=1758,
                                subsample=0.68))])
```

I would like some help, please.

Thank you,

regards.

Comment: Please check your current working directory `import os; print(os.getcwd())` to make sure `"model.pkl"` is present in that path.

Also I am assuming here that `X_val` is present and not null.

Comment: my .pkl is in its right path, and X_val is also set by a split of the data

Comment: It seems that you need to properly access the model inside your pipepline, such as `explainer = shap.Explainer(model["classifier"])`